# Ubuntu squid with windows 2012 active directory users authentication

Tags: 14.04

I need to install Ubuntu proxy server with windows 2012 R2 standers active directory users integrated for option please help me or suggest some documents.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing recently and I found the howto below really helpful.  It is however in Russian.  Since I don't speak Russian I used Google translate to convert the page to english.  The translation was fine and made the howto perfectly usable.  Maybe it can help you as well.

```
https://blog.it-kb.ru/2014/06/16/forward-proxy-squid-3-3-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-part-2-prepare-separate-vhd-disk-partition-for-squid-cache-in-fdisk/
```

Cheers.